# How to validate a password before registering user in .Net Core Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

In my .Net Razor Pages app, I'm using Identity to edit and register a new user. There are Model Validation attributes set and along with JQuery validate.js and validate-unobtrusive.js I use AJAX to check for password nulls, minimum length, etc. on the server.

But in Startup.cs there are also options set in the AddDefaultIdentity() (i.e. options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true; options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 3;... ) that I would like to apply/verify BEFORE the user is registered. These work great when an existing user is prompted to change/reset their password (via ChangePasswordAsync() and ResetPasswordAsync(), respectively) but how do I do this before _userManager.CreateAsync() to register a new user?

The reason I ask is that after all validations are complete, I display a Modal for the user prompting them to verify that they are about to create a 'New' account with this unique 'Email' and 'User Name'. With ChangePasswordAsync() and ResetPasswordAsync() the ChangePasswordResult.Succeeded and ResetPasswordResult.Succeeded return errors ONLY if an error occurs, otherwise they change/reset the password. But when registering a new user, I don't want to register in DB unless they click the 'Register' button in the Modal first.

So the question is: is there a way to enforce the Statup.cs password options when I check the ModelState.IsValid (via AJAX) on the server and before I call CreateAsync() to create the new user?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers... :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do the ASP.NET Core password validation rules have no effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69768906/why-do-the-asp-net-core-password-validation-rules-have-no-effect)

Comment: Yes @RahulSharma, tks. The passwordValidator.ValidateAsync() returns a list of errors, which is exactly what I needed. See the snippet Update below. Cheers ... :)

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Thanks to @RahulSharma and the previous question he referenced, the answer was surprisingly simple. Here is an example with HTML formatted ErrorList if anyone is interested:

```
    string ErrorList = "";
    IdentityResult result;
    var NewUser = new ApplicationUser
    {
        UserName = Input.UserName,
        Email = Input.Email
    };

    foreach (IPasswordValidator<ApplicationUser> passwordValidator in _userManager.PasswordValidators)
    {
        result = await passwordValidator.ValidateAsync(_userManager, NewUser, Input.Password);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                if (ErrorList != "") ErrorList = ErrorList + "<br />";
                ErrorList += error.Description;
            }
        }
    }
```